# Book suggestion on computational molecular evolution

Tags: bioinformatics, book-recommendation, molecular-evolution

I'm currently reading [Computational Molecular Evolution](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198567022) by Yang. Can you recommend alternative books?

I am finding it to be lacking on conceptual discussion (it's more focussed on the mathematics and statistical intricacies). I'd like to find something which discusses why we do the things, and the strengths and weaknesses of the ideas, which are presented in the Yang book whilst not being overly specialist - more of an introductory text to the field.

Any introduction to phylogenetics books??

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest the course of Coursera.org:

### [Computational Molecular Evolution](https://www.coursera.org/course/molevol)

By Anders Gorm Pedersen

Technical University of Denmark (DTU)

PS: Do tell us if you found a better book!